# Horizontal overflow due to file-chooser on ios Simulator

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3 application which is not `user-scalable`:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

The page contains a form which is also fully responsive:

Now, as soon as I include a file-picker to upload images, the width of the page is increased so that horizontal scrollbars appear:

[image: screenshot]

As soon as I remove the file-field from the form the UI-glitch disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the problem was related to the file-field in my form. The following entry in my CSS caused the problem:

```
body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Removing this entry did fix the problem and the horizontal overflow is no longer there.